# Store column values in array with mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

I'm trying to collect the column values into an array so I can then get an average of all the values. Here's my code so far:

```
    $conn = new mysqli($hn, $un, $pw, $db);
/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
}

$average_hdpe = "SELECT hdpe FROM $region";
$average_hdpe_result = $conn->query($average_hdpe) or die(mysqli_error($conn)) ;
$average_hdpe_array = $average_hdpe_result->fetch_array();

print_r($average_hdpe_array);
```

running the above code prints:

Array ( [0] => 1147 [hdpe] => 1147 )

I was expecting 4 entries: 1147, 1152, 1157, 1157. 
Could someone suggest what I'm doing wrong? presumably fetch_array() doesn't do what I thought.

Comment: You're only fetching the first row. Try using `fetch_all()` instead of `fetch_array()`, or keep `fetch_array()` and loop the results. The manual for these functions holds good examples. (You're also getting double values because its fetching both numeric and associative, you could `fetch_assoc()` to just get associative).

Comment: You are confusing procedural and object oriented methods

Comment: Why not using SELECT AVG(hdpe) FROM $region ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  $average_hdpe = "SELECT hdpe FROM $region";
    $average_hdpe_result = $conn->query($average_hdpe) or die(mysqli_error($conn)) ;
     $array = array();//create empty array
     while($row = $average_hdpe_result->fetch_array()){//loop to get all results
         $array[] = $row;//grab everything and store inside array
     }
print_r($array);//this should give you everything
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a array store the fetched data in the array

```
$conn = new mysqli($hn, $un, $pw, $db);
/* check connection */
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $conn->connect_error);
exit();
}

$average_hdpe = "SELECT hdpe FROM $region";
$average_hdpe_result = $conn->query($average_hdpe) or die() ;
$average_hdpe_array = array();
while($row = $average_hdpe_result->fetch_assoc()){
$average_hdpe_array[] = $row;
}

print_r($average_hdpe_array);
```